# if function result is Z for X times, call another function

Tags: javascript, function, loops, mousemove

I have a function `foo()` that is fired on mouse move, so as long as mouse is moving, it is always called.

`foo()` can be any number. I need to fire another function if `foo()` result is 100, for 3 times.

How can I do that?

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const whatINeed = foo(e)
  // here we go: foo result is always a number
  // if that number is 100 for 3 times
  // fire another function
})
```

Comment: three times or three times in a row? You'll need a variable to hold the count of how many times foo() was 100, and when it reaches 3, you fire another function ... simple case of comparison (x == 100) addition (x = x + 1) and another comparison (x == 3)

Comment: three times, no need to be in a row. Could you please elaborate an answer? not quite sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (() =>
    let count=0;
    return (e) => {
        const whatINeed = foo(e)
        if(whatINeed == 100) {
            if(++count == 3) {
                //fire another function
            }
        }
    };
})());
```